# Second event showing up too quickly in javafx event handling

Tags: javafx, event-handling

Right now as soon as the user clicks the first button the second one appears instantly, with or without thread. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// Register an event filter for a single node and a specific event type
getBtn1().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
        event -> {

            if (event.getSource().equals(getBtn1())) {
                getBtn1().setGraphic(new ImageView(getCrossImage()));
                event.consume();
            }
            if (event.isConsumed()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                getBtn2().setGraphic(new ImageView(getNoughtsImage()));
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not block the JavaFX application thread. Otherwise layout/rendering is paused until the method call completes. Since event filters run on the application thread you need to rewrite the code and allow the handler to complete without delay.

It's possible to use a `PauseTransition` for this purpose:

```
// Register an event filter for a single node and a specific event type
getBtn1().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
    event -> {

        if (event.getSource().equals(getBtn1())) {
            getBtn1().setGraphic(new ImageView(getCrossImage()));
            event.consume();

            PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.1));
            pause.setOnFinished(evt -> getBtn2().setGraphic(new ImageView(getNoughtsImage())));
            pause.play();
        }
    });
```